# "Ambiguous overload" в шаблонной перегрузке функции с variadic templates

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

сообщество!

Помогите разобраться, почему следующий код не компилируется:

```
struct Format {};

template<typename F, typename ... Args>
void f(int, Args...) {}

template<typename F, typename T, typename ... Args>
void f(T, Args...) {}

int main () {
    f<Format>(1, 1);
}
```

Что интересно, если поменять сигнатуру на

```
template<typename F, typename T, typename ... Args>
void f(F, T, Args...)
```

или убрать первый шаблонный параметр, компилируется нормально.

Comment: По аргументам шаблона генерируется код.  У вас же есть аргумент F, но нет кода использующего его каким то образом. Поэтому его нужно или убрать или использовать

Comment: А какое поведение тут ожидается? Как ни странно, [ругается только g++, а clang++ и vc++ собирают как есть](https://godbolt.org/g/pd5DuH).

Comment: Хочется добиться того, что при вызове  f<Format>(1, 1); вызывалась бы  первая функцияf(int, Args...), а при вызове, например, f<Format>("hello", 1)  -- вторая. Собственно это и происходит, если шаблон F убрать или поменять сигнатуру.
Шаблонный аргумент F используется в теле функций, но в вопросе привожу максимально упрощенный код.

Comment: Выглядит как баг GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить явную проверку типа первого аргумента функции и отбрасывать один из шаблонов по [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Format {};

template<typename F, typename T, typename ... Args>
::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_same_v<T, int>>
f(T, Args...) {std::cout << "1" << ::std::endl;}

template<typename F, typename T, typename ... Args>
::std::enable_if_t<!::std::is_same_v<T, int>>
f(T, Args...) {std::cout << "2" << ::std::endl;}

int main () {
    f<Format>(1, 1);
    f<Format>("sdf", 1);
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/jpBB1W)

В случае, если проверяемый параметр более сложный, например шаблон, то можно реализовать дополнительную проверку:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Format {};

template<typename T> struct Meta{};

template<typename T> struct
is_meta_wrapper: public ::std::false_type {};

template<typename T> struct
is_meta_wrapper<Meta<T>>: public ::std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
constexpr auto const is_meta_wrapper_v{is_meta_wrapper<T>::value};

template<typename F, typename T, typename ... Args>
::std::enable_if_t<is_meta_wrapper_v<T>>
f(T, Args...) {std::cout << "1" << ::std::endl;}

template<typename F, typename T, typename ... Args>
::std::enable_if_t<!is_meta_wrapper_v<T>>
f(T, Args...) {std::cout << "2" << ::std::endl;}

int main () {
    f<Format>(Meta<int>{}, 1);
    f<Format>(1, 1);
    f<Format>("sdf", 1);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vcCLL83GADUhqSm0)

Comment: Спасибо, такая идея решения проблемы была. Может, вы можете дать ответ, почему мой пример не компилируется. Как происходит name resolving, в чем принципиальное отличие от варианта, где нет первого шаблонного параметра.

Comment: @ПолинаОлеговнаЛукина по-моему это баг в gcc.

Comment: к тому же на практике у меня ветвление возникает, не в случае,если параметр int, а в случае, если параметр - определенная тоже шаблонная структура. Это уже не понятно, как написать с enable_if.

Comment: Например [Bug 67228 - Template partial ordering failure ambiguous overload](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67228). @ПолинаОлеговнаЛукина Если вместо `int` там шаблонная структура, то этот способ должен по-прежнему работать, только условие подправить навроде `is_same_v<T, Struct<int>>`.

Comment: а как поступить, если есть структура-обертка, над всеми типами, которая, условно, хранит значение и мета-информацию, и нужно проверить, что в функцию передали именно такую обертку. То есть должно быть что-то такое `template <class Fmt, class T, class ...Ts> void f (meta<T> head, const Ts& ...tail)`  и, соответственно парная функция `template <class Fmt, class T, class ...Ts> void f (T head, const Ts& ...tail)`

Comment: @ПолинаОлеговнаЛукина Дополнил ответ.